# Creating copy of database through stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have example database and in my asp.net project I need to create copy of that database with another name. I'm thinking of doing it with a stored procedure.

Is it possible? If so, how?

Comment: Back it up then restore with a new name? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa176752(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: Don't know if its possible, buy why?  If you have access to the server to add a new database, just go in with SQL management and clone the db.

Comment: check this blog article for [sample sql code](http://weblogs.asp.net/mschwarz/archive/2004/08/26/220735.aspx)

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way to accomplish this is by doing a backup and restore of the database:

```
backup database YourDatabaseName
to disk = 'C:\Yourbackupdir\BackupFile.bak'
with copy_only;
go
```

And then you can do the restore accordingly:

```
restore database YourNewDatabaseName
from disk = 'C:\Yourbackupdir\BackupFile.bak';
go
```

Likewise, if this is on the same server or if you don't have a similar directory structure for the database files to live on, then you may need to specify the `MOVE` clause:

```
restore database YourNewDatabaseName
from disk = 'C:\Yourbackupdir\BackupFile.bak'
with
    move 'YourDataFileName' to 'C:\NewLocation\DataFile1.mdf',
    move 'YourLogFileName' to 'C:\NewLocation\LogFile1.ldf';
go
```

You can get a list of the files by running `restore filelistonly from disk = 'C:\Yourbackupdir\BackupFile.bak';`.

Comment: +1 For `with copy_only`